# Magento 2: new attribute not showing in list configurable product

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, configurable-product, magento-2.0.2

I've created new configurable product and clicked Create Configurations at the bottom of the product page. None of my new attributes are listed here.

Am I missing something?

I have tried to work your way Asish Hira, but when i go to

> stores >  attributes > product

I can't actually drag anything. So i tried going to

> stores > attribute set

In this area i am actually able to drag attributes to my default or new (chair) attribute set. But when i have dragged them, saved the attribute set and reindexed all indexes, i still don't see any attributes in the configurable product list.

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use an Attribute for Configurations, you have to make sure, that it has the Scope Global.

That is (I think) like this, because it does not make sense to override a configuration variant on store or store view level.

Answer (score 4):

In short, your attribute must have *'frontend_input' = 'select',  'is_user_defined' = 1, 'is_global' = 1*

Please see answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206549/4831

Comment: As of 2.2.5, the attribute must also either have no product type apply_to selected, or all three of simple, virtual, and configurable must be selected. More details here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/246331/15939