# Creating configurable product but size attribute not available to choose in Step 1 of creating configurations

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

Hope you can help.

I've set up a size attribute in STORES > PRODUCT.

I've created a new attribute set in STORES > ATTRIBUTE SET and dragged the 'size' attribute into the middle column.

After doing this, I go to setup a new Configurable product.

1. I select Add Configurable Product.
2. Select the new attribute set from the drop down.
3. Enter the basic product details and click on the Create Configurations button.

In Step 1, only the color attribute is available for selection and I can't get the size attribute to appear.

I've tried changing the details in the size attribute to the same settings as in the color attribute but still no luck. Also changed to Global and has a greyed out 'multiple select' drop down.

Any ideas as to where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Solution from @Matt B makes my day! Thanks man!!!! I've been searching for DAYS and simply change de DB table (apply_to) to: simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable
Works like a charm!
;-)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145311)

Comment: I dont understand the solution can you please explain what i need to do? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

There are several other questions related to this problem, and I have not seen this mentioned in any of them.

In addition to the requirements posted by others  (attribute should be global, user_defined, visible, and have input type select - or another single selection type) , as of version 2.2.5 there is also requirement that in order to be available for use in configurations an attribute must either have no apply_to (Product Types) specified, or the apply_to must include *all three* of the following product types, simple,virtual,and configurable.

It is not clear to me if this is a bug or a feature.  Here is the applicable code from the file `vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\ConfigurableAttributeHandler.php`

```
public function isAttributeApplicable($attribute)
{
    $types = [
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE,
    ];
    return !$attribute->getApplyTo() || count(array_diff($types, $attribute->getApplyTo())) === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use attribute for configurable product you should set its Scope-Global, Catalog Input Type - Dropdown. If you created Color attribute with Input Type - Multiple Select, you can't change its input type to Dropdown. Try to re-create the attribute with correct input type, add its options and generate configurable again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your attribute scope  is set to **"Global"** in attribute properties

Refer below screenshot:
[image]

After that save your attributes and clear the cache.