# Magento 2 : Created Custom Product Attribute but Not showing in Configuration Section

Tags: magento-2.1.3, magento-2.1.4

I Have Created custom attribute for configurable  products. It is Showing in Add configurable Product section.
[image]

But I Can't get those attributes in below section.

[image]

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'paper_size',
        [
            'group' => 'Pricing Calculator',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'sort_order' => 10,
            'label' => 'Card Size',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Lts\MultipleDropdown\Model\Config\Source\Optionssize',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to'=>'configurable'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Show your custom attribute code

Comment: Have you set this attribute in attribute set?

Comment: custom attribute code added.

Comment: Custom Attributes are set in Default Attribute Set.

Comment: are you created product is contains default attribute set?

Comment: Yes, When I am creating New Product , My selected Attribute set is default.

Comment: please just run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Already Used those commands
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento indexer:reindex,
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Please Help Me out With This problem.

Answer (score 2):

1- Please check that Attribute you have created is assigned to the
attribute set.

2- Please run the reindex command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

3- flush the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add the custom attribute to the 'Attribute Set' the configurable product is using.

You can have different configurable products using different attribute sets. Check the attribute set used for your configurable product here:

- Catalog -> Product -> [Edit] -> General -> Attribute Set

Add the custom attribute to the attribute set used by your configurable product here:

- Store - Attribute Set -> [Edit] -> drag unsigned attributes to the attribute set

Answer (score 2):

this is the good code to create a product attribute that can be used for configurable product for Magento 2.3.

The required parameters are :

```
'source'=> \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class
'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'user_defined' => true,
'visible' => true,
```

complete code

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'size',
        [
            'group' => 'Erp',
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Taille',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 20,
            'position'=> 0,
            'source'=> \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

See how the attribute grid collection is created in

*\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Attributes::getData*

then *\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeHandler::getApplicableAttributes*

```
return $collection->addFieldToFilter(
        'frontend_input',
        'select'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'is_user_defined',
        1
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'is_global',
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
    );
```

You should set is_user_defined to true.
(test on Magento 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'paper_size',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Size',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => implode(',', [Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL, Configurable::TYPE_CODE]),
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => true
            ]
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom attribute must have global scope to be used for configurable products, see [Magento 2: new attribute not showing in list configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111585/magento-2-new-attribute-not-showing-in-list-configurable-product)

Answer (score 0):

In my case module was **disabled** Xd.

Check module Status: `bin/magento module:status`